# Displaying model's multi-level categories in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade, multi-level

So, I've created a model called 'books'. Each book has a set of genres (with the model Genre) that function as nested categories, so a book might be fiction>adults>science fiction>cyberpunk or non-fiction>young adult>history>Roman etc.

There is a many-to-many relationship between books and genres and a pivot table to connect the two.

The Genre model looks like so:

```
class Genre extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    use HasRecursiveRelationships;


    public function books()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(books::class);
    }

    public static function tree()
    {
        $allgenres = Genre::get();

        $rootgenres = $allgenres->whereNull('parent_id');

        self::formatTree($rootgenres, $allgenres);

        return $rootgenres;
    }

    private static function formatTree($genres, $allgenres)
    {
        foreach ($genres as $genre) {
            $genre->children = $allgenres->where('parent_id', $genre->id)->values();

            if ($genre->children->isNotEmpty()) {
                self::formatTree($genre->children, $allgenres);
            }
        }
    }
```

And the books model like so:

```
class Books extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function writer(): BelongsTo 
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Writer::class);

    }


    public function genres()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Genre::class);
    }
}
```

Then in book.blade.php I've written the following:

```
<div>
        @foreach ($book->genres as $genre)
        <div>{{ $genre->name }}
            @foreach ($genre->children as $child)
            <div class="ml-5">{{ $child->name }}
                @foreach ($child->children as $child2)
                <div class="ml-5">{{ $child2->name }}
                    
                    @foreach ($child->children as $child3)
                    <div class="ml-5">{{ $child3->name }}</div>
                    @endforeach

                </div>
                @endforeach

            </div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
```

It then dumps out every single genre in the model like so:

[image]

What I want is for it to display only the selected genres for this particular book. It looks like what I have so far will only display the topmost level of the specific book's relationship but that relationship falls apart when it goes to the child layer.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get 4 levels of genres, try:

```
$book = Books::where('id', $bookId)->with([
    'genres' => function ($query) {
        $query->whereNull('parent_id');
    },
    'genres.children' => function ($query) use ($bookId) {
        $query->wherePivot('book_id', $bookId);
    },
    'genres.children.children' => function ($query) use ($bookId) {
        $query->wherePivot('book_id', $bookId);
    },
    'genres.children.children.children' => function ($query) use ($bookId) {
        $query->wherePivot('book_id', $bookId);
    }
])->first();
```